# How many hexadecimal chains of numbers of length 6 are there with an "A" in the first position or with "F"...?

Tags: inclusion-exclusion

How many hexadecimal chains of numbers of length 6 are there with an "A" in the first position or with "F" in the 3rd and 4th position or a "0" in the last position? Only chains of numbers with at least one 
hex value less than 9 should be counted. The or link is not exclusive.

**My guess:**

First I use "Inclusion-exclusion principle" for the ""A" in the first position or with "F" in the 3rd and 4th position or a "0" in the last position" $\rightarrow(A \cup B \cup C ) = |A| +|B|+|C|-|A \cap B| -|A \cap C|-|B \cap C| + |A \cap B \cap C|$

|A| = $16^{5}$

|B| = $16^{4}$

|C| = $16^{5}$

**solution (formula):** = $2089216$

Now I don't know how I can get the result for the "hex value less than 9".

---

I wrote a short program that gave me the solution of $2070352$, but as I said I don't know how I can get the right solution.

#sendhelp

Comment: You also have to add $|A \cap B \cap C|$ in the formula for $|A \cup B \cup C|$.

Comment: ah yes i did, but i forgot to wrote it!

Answer (score 1):

Hint: if $D$ is the set of chains with at least one hex value less than $9$, then $D$ is the complement $D'$ of the set of chains where all values are at least $9$. $D'$ has $7^6$ elements, so $D$ has $16^6 - 7^6$ elements.

Comment: I've came to this conclusion too. But how do I calculate $D \cap (A \cap B \cap C)$?

Comment: By more applications of the inclusion-exclusion principle.

Comment: how does $A \cap D$ look like? Cause I also tried that, but I got $16^{5} - 7^{6}$ and this is wrong I believe.